How to solve $(a+b+c-x)^2 x \ge 4abc$, with $x \lt a+b+c$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$?
I'm interested in solving a non-trivial cubic inequality coming from some physical arguments.
So, the first part of my question is dedicated to the creation of the (necessarily physical) context, the second part to the transition to mathematical language, since my goal here is to find a relation from the cubic inequality I will present, along with other conditions.
I was interested to calculate analitically the maximum temperature we can achieve in one of the systems for three thermodynamic systems at initial arbitrary absolute temperatures $T_1, T_2, T_3$. As Callen's Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics and an other interesting source suggest, we let the two cooler systems obtain a temperature $T_{\mathrm{cooler}}$ and let the hotter system obtain a temperature $T_{\mathrm{hotter}}$ so that, by conservation of energy, we have
\begin{align}
T_\mathrm{hotter}+2T_\mathrm{cooler}=T_1+T_2+T_3 \tag{$\mathrm{Equation}\ \ast$}.
\end{align}
WLoG, we can assume that system $1$ ends up the hottest, so we integrate the entropy changes so that:
$$\Delta S=C\ln\left(\frac{T_\mathrm{hotter}}{T_1}\right)+C\ln\left(\frac{T_\mathrm{cooler}}{T_2}\right)+C\ln\left(\frac{T_\mathrm{cooler}}{T_3}\right) \iff \Delta S = C\ln\Bigg(\frac{ T_\mathrm{hotter} T_\mathrm{cooler}^{2} }{T_1 T_2 T_3}\Bigg).$$
Since $\Delta S \geq 0$, we have $\ln\Bigg(\dfrac{ T_\mathrm{hotter} T_\mathrm{cooler}^{2} }{T_1 T_2 T_3}\Bigg) \geq 0,$
or
$$T_\mathrm{hotter}T_\mathrm{cooler}^2\ge T_1T_2T_3.$$
Plugging the energy conservation ($\text{equation} \ \ast$) into this inequality, we obtain:
$$(T_1+T_2+T_3-T_\mathrm{hotter})^2T_\mathrm{hotter}\ge 4T_1T_2T_3\ \tag{$\mathrm{inequality \ 1}$}.$$
Moreover, we can’t cool anything to $0 \ \mathrm{K}$ or below, we have also to satisfy
$$T_\mathrm{cooler} \gt 0 \implies \frac{T_1+T_2+T_3-T_\mathrm{hotter}}{2}\gt 0,$$
or
$$T_\mathrm{hotter}\lt T_1+T_2+T_3\ \tag{$\mathrm{inequality \ 2}$}.$$
Eventually, absolute temperatures have to be positive. So:
$$T_\mathrm{hotter} \gt 0, \quad T_1 \gt 0, \quad T_2 \gt 0, \quad T_3 \gt 0\ \tag{$\mathrm{inequalities \ 3,4,5,6}$}.$$
Callen solves these inequalities graphically, but I would like to solve $(\mathrm{inequality \ 1})$ analytically.

Here we can make the step to pure mathematical language. Let
$$T_{\mathrm{hotter}} \mapsto x, \quad T_1 \mapsto a, \quad T_2 \mapsto b, \quad T_3 \mapsto c.$$
We have:
$$\boxed{(a+b+c-x)^2 x\ge 4abc} \tag{$\mathrm{inequality \ 1}$.}$$,
a non-trivial cubic equation in $x$.
The inequalities
$$x \lt a+b+c\ \tag{$\mathrm{inequality \ 2}$}$$
and
$$x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$$
represent the necessary conditions.
Are there analytic specific methods to solve $(\mathrm{inequality \ 1})$ for $x$, given also the other conditions?

So it seems like you want the largest root of the cubic $ (A-x)^2x = B$? There's a formula for that. Are you looking for it in a certain form?

Under the substitution $y=x/(a+b+c)$, the relevant inequalities become $$y(1-y)^2\geq \frac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3},\quad 0<y<1$$
This effectively eliminates $a,b,c$ in favor of a single quantity $u:=4abc/(a+b+c)^3$. Writing $$f(y)=y(1-y)^2-u$$ the problem amounts to finding the subinterval of $[0,1]$ for which $f(y)\geq 0$.
However, $u>0$ itself is positive (since $a,b,c$ are) and moreover is bounded above per the AM-GM inequality:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq (abc)^{1/3}\implies u=\frac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3}\leq \frac{4}{27}$$
with equality only if $a=b=c$. Furthermore, note that when $u=4/27$ we have the factorization
$$f(y)=y(1-y)^2-\frac{4}{27}=(y-4/3)(y-1/3)^2$$
Thus $f(y)\leq 0$ for all $y\in [0,1]$, with equality only if $y=1/3$. Hence in the case $a=b=c$ the only solution to $f(y)\geq 0$ in this interval is $y=1/3\implies x=(a+b+c)/3=a=b=c$. (This makes physical sense: If all three systems are already at a common temperature $T$, then the systems are already in thermal equilibrium.)
If instead $0<u<4/27$, note that $f(0)=f(1)=-u<0$ and $f(1/3)=4/27 - u >0$. Hence the intermediate value theorem implies that the intervals $(0,1/3)$ and $(1/3,1)$ each contain at least one real root. Additionally, since $f'(y)=(3y-1)(y-1)$ we deduce that $f$ is strictly increasing ($f'>0$) on $(0,1/3)$ and strictly decreasing ($f'<0$) on $(1/3,1)$. Hence these roots must each be unique. Denoting these real roots as $y_1,y_2$ respectively we conclude that $f(y)\geq 0$ for $y\in (y_1,y_2)$. Thus in these cases there is some range of possible hot temperatures, with the equilibrium temperature of the three systems (corresponding to $y=1/3$) always being allowed.
To actually determine expressions for $y_1,y_2$ is more involved and perhaps not so interesting, since it amounts to solving the relevant cubic equation. However, since the three real roots are real and in general non-rational we can appeal to Viète's trigonometric solution of the depressed cubic. After some manipulation, including discarding the third root for which $y>1$, this yields the relevant real roots as
$$
y_{1,2}=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\pm \frac{\theta(u)}{3}\right),\qquad \theta(u):=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{27u}{2}-1\right)
$$
with $y_1,y_2$ taking the negative and positive signs respectively. Hence the solution set can be parametrized as $y=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\phi}{3}\right)$ with $\phi\in[-\theta(u),\theta(u)]$. The case $u=4/27$ yields $\theta(4/27)=0\implies y_{1,2}=1/3$ as above.

+1 Beautiful answer. However, I have some doubts and many questions. 1) 1st doubt: why did you write $y(1-y)^2-u\geq \dfrac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3}$. If $y = \dfrac{x}{a+b+c}$, shouldn't it be $y(1-y)^2 \ge \dfrac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3} \iff y(1-y)^2 - \dfrac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3} \ge 0$, and, setting $u := \dfrac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3}$ (as you said), $y(1-y)^2 - u \ge 0$? This would justify your next passage: finding the subinterval of $[0,1]$ for which $f(y) = y(1-y)^2 - u \ge 0$. 2) 2nd doubt: when exploiting AM-GM, you wrote $u=\dfrac{abc}{(a+b+c)^3}$, but shouldn't it be $u=\dfrac{4abc}{(a+b+c)^3}$?

3) 3rd doubt: in the final sentence you wrote $\theta(0) = 0$, but shouldn't it be $\theta(\frac{4}{27}) = 0$? Indeed, according to your analytic expression, $\theta(0) = \arccos (-1) = \pi \ne 0$. Is this another typo? After that, my actual questions begin. A) 1st question: in one of the last paragraphs, you say "Hence each interval contains exactly one real root". Why is this obvious? Could you cite the Theorems you exploited to state this fact?

B) 2nd question: immediately after, you say "Denoting these real roots as $y_1, y_2$ respectively we conclude that $f(y) \ge 0$ for $y \in (y_1,y_2)$". Why? What is the evidence for $f(y) \ge 0 \iff y \in (y_1, y_2)$? Could you cite the Theorems you exploited to state this fact? C) 3rd question: in the last paragraph you say "with $y_1,y_2$ taking the negative and positive roots respectively". How can $y$ be negative if $T_{\mathrm{hotter}} \mapsto x > 0$, $T_1, T_2, T_3 \mapsto a,b,c >0$ and $y = \dfrac{x}{a+b+c}$? AFAIK both $y_1$ and $y_2$ should be positive.

D) 4th question: Could you expand on and explain with more detail how did you obtain $y_1, y_2$ and $\theta(u)$ from "manipolation of Viète's trigonometric solution of the depressed cubic"?. So... E) 5th question: How did you proceed "discarding the third root for which $y \gt 1$"?
